# DateTime in Laravel -- Call to a member function add() on a non-object

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to use DateTime in Laravel 4 and i keep getting Call to a member function add() on a non-object when i try and use the add function and cant work out why.

This is my code

```
    if(isset($_POST['from']) && isset($_POST['direction']) && isset($_POST['product']) && isset($_POST['operator'])){

        $businessid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['operator']);
    $direction = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['direction']);

    $dateStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y', $_POST['from']);
    $dateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y', $_POST['from']);

        if($direction == 'first')
        {
            $dateEnd->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));
        }
        else if($direction == 'right')
        {
            $dateStart->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
            $dateEnd->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
        }
        else if($direction == 'left')
        {
            $dateStart->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
            if($dateStart < $todaysDate) {  $dateStart = $todaysDate; }
            $dateEnd->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        }
        else if($direction == 'date')
        {
            $dateStart->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
            while($dateStart < $todaysDate) {   $dateStart->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); }
            $dateEnd->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
        }
```

Any ideas would be a big help thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using it on static you can simply instantiate an new DateTime Object. Consider this example:

```
$from = '2014-06-06'; // sample data
$dateEnd = new DateTime();
$dateEnd->createFromFormat('D M d Y', $from);
$dateEnd->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));

echo $dateEnd->format('D M d Y');
```